# A problem about division and demonstration $a^n-b^n=(a-b)(a^{n-1}+a^{n-2} b+...+ab^{n-2}+b^{n-1})$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

"What is left of the division $4^{2013}$ by $3$?"

Comment: Is the real problem to find a relation between the title and the body of the question?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Note that since $4\equiv 1\pmod 3$ we have 
$$4^{2013}\equiv 1^{2013}\equiv 1\pmod{3}.$$
 So the remainder is $1$.

**Remark:** The above is a small demonstration of the power of the congruence notation introduced by Gauss.

Comment: I will see this content this semester now, I am most anxious.

Comment: And Demonstration? Its also do using this method?

Comment: By demonstration I meant sample, or example. But it is easy to show that the arithmetic of congruences works like it should, that for example if $a\equiv a'\pmod{m}$ and $b\equiv b'\pmod{m}$ then $ab\equiv a'b'\pmod{m}$. A similar thing is true for addition.

Answer (score 6):

$$4^{2013}-1=(4-1)(4^{2012}+4^{2011}+\;...+4^{2}+4+1)\\4^{2013}=3(4^{2012}+4^{2011}+\;...+4^{2}+4+1)+1$$Soon, the rest is $1$

> Show: $a^n-b^n=(a-b)(a^{n-1}+a^{n-2} b+...+ab^{n-2}+b^{n-1})\;\;\;\forall n\in \mathbb{N},\; n\geq 2$
>
> Induction:
>
> I) First, test to 2 $$a^2-b^2=(a-b)(a^{2-1}-b^{2-1})=(a-b)(a+b)\;\;\;\;\;\text{OK}$$
>
> II) Hypothesis: $$a^n-b^n=(a-b)(a^{n-1}+a^{n-2} b+...+ab^{n-2}+b^{n-1})$$
>
> III) Thesis: $$a^{n+1}-b^{n+1}=(a-b)(a^{n}+a^{n-1} b+...+ab^{n-1}+b^{n})$$ Show: $$\begin{align}a^{n+1}-b^{n+1} &= aa^n-bb^n\\ &= aa^n-bb^n\underbrace{+ab^n-ab^n}_{=0}\\ &= aa^n-ab^n-bb^n+ab^n\\ &= a\underbrace{(a^n-b^n)}_{\text{hypothesis}}+b^n(a-b)\\ &= a((a-b)(a^{n-1}+a^{n-2} b+...+ab^{n-2}+b^{n-1}))+b^n(a-b)\\ &= (a-b)(a)(a^{n-1}+a^{n-2} b+...+ab^{n-2}+b^{n-1})+b^n\\ &= (a-b)(a^n+a^{n-1}b+\;...+a^2b^{n-2}+ab^{n-1}+b^n)\;\;\;\;\;\Box\end{align}$$

Comment: Quite off topic, but how did you type all this so fast? I had been typing in a question for some 15-20 minutes! I'd like to know if there's any special editor for mathjax that makes typing fast.

Comment: @ParthThakkar Is slowly getting familiar with the language LaTeX, and vc is copying and pasting the commands :)

Comment: I have a good practice of mathjax, but still it takes a lot of time to actually type in stuff. Amazing that you could type the whole answer within 1 minute!! And btw what is vc?

Comment: (+1) I've redone your chain of equations at the end to make it clearer. See what you think.

Comment: @CameronBuie: It was good, very good, thank you.